# How to convert a date with "nd","rd", "th" into a yyyy-mm-dd format Javasciript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dates like:

```
dates=['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019']
```

and I want to return them as an array in the YYYY-MM-DD format. 
so far I have this:

```
function formatDate(dates) {
var t=[];
dates.map(function(date){
 var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    t.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
});
console.log(t);


    return t;
}
var dates = ['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019']
 console.log(formatDate(dates));
```

but this gives me :

```
[NaN-NaN-NaN,NaN-NaN-NaN,NaN-NaN-NaN]
```

since its not able to recognize the date with "th", "nd".any idea how to fix this so that I get the o/p as:

```
[2014-10-02,2014-10-20,2019-05-20]
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nakpchvf/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove letters.

```js
function formatDate(dates) {
var t=[];
dates.map(function(date){
    let datePieces = date.split(' ');
    datePieces[0] = datePieces[0].replace(/\D+/g, '');
    var d = new Date(datePieces.join(' ')),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    t.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
});


    return t;
}
var dates = ['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019']
 console.log(formatDate(dates));
```

Basically above I take each date and split it into 3 different parts. I then fix the first index (the one causing an issue) by removing any non-numerical characters. After that I can recombine to form your date string :).

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [moment](http://momentjs.com/), or if using it is an option, it's fairly simple:

```js
const dates=['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019'];

dates.forEach(date => {
  console.log(moment(date, 'Do MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use replace() function to replace these words with empty like this

```
function formatDate(dates) {
    var t=[];
    dates.map(function(date){
        var words=["th","nd"];
        for(var i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            date=date.replace(words[i],"");
        }
     var d = new Date(date),
     month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
     day = '' + d.getDate(),
     year = d.getFullYear();
     if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
     if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
     t.push([year, month, day].join('-'));
     });
     console.log(t);
    return t;
}
var dates = ['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019']
console.log(formatDate(dates));
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any external library and nevertheless compact:

```js
function formatDate(d) {
    return new Date(d.replace(/^(\d+)\w+/,"$1")).toLocaleString().replace(/^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+),.*$/, "$3-$2-$1")
} 
console.log(['2nd Oct 2014','20th Oct 2014','20th May 2019'].map(formatDate))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to obtain the result without using any external library, you can try like this using the concept of regular expressions for replacement of `st`, `nd`,  `rd`,  `th` kind of substrings with `''` (blank string) from date strings in array.

> - I have also used ternary operator `?:` for applying an inline if-else to convert month/date like `1` to `01` etc.
> - I have also used **map()** method defined on arrays to skip the use of loop.

```
function formatDates(dates) {
    return dates.map((date) => {
        const d = new Date(date.replace(/(st)|(nd)|(rd)|(th)/ig, ""));
        const yyyy = d.getFullYear();
        const mm = "" + (d.getMonth() + 1);
        const dd = "" + d.getDate();

        return  `${yyyy}-${mm.length === 1? "0" + mm: mm}-${dd.length === 1? "0" + dd: dd}` ;
    }) 
}

var dates = ['2nd Oct 2014', '20th Oct 2014', '20th May 2019']
console.log(formatDates(dates)); // [ '2014-10-02', '2014-10-20', '2019-05-20' ]
```